# pandas series bfill first half, ffill second half

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I had:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3,1415])
s = pd.Series(np.random.choice((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan),
                               (50,), p=(.1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .5)))
```

I want to back fill in missing values for the first half of the series and forward fill for the second half of the series.  Middle out, if you will.

Expected output

```
0     4.0
1     4.0
2     4.0
3     4.0
4     4.0
5     0.0
6     1.0
7     1.0
8     1.0
9     1.0
10    1.0
11    1.0
12    1.0
13    1.0
14    1.0
15    1.0
16    1.0
17    1.0
18    4.0
19    1.0
20    2.0
21    0.0
22    0.0
23    NaN
24    NaN
25    NaN
26    NaN
27    3.0
28    2.0
29    4.0
30    4.0
31    4.0
32    4.0
33    0.0
34    0.0
35    0.0
36    0.0
37    2.0
38    2.0
39    2.0
40    2.0
41    1.0
42    1.0
43    0.0
44    2.0
45    2.0
46    2.0
47    2.0
48    2.0
49    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just operate on the two halves independently here:

```
In [71]: s.ix[:len(s)/2].bfill().append(s.ix[1+len(s)/2:].ffill())
Out[71]:
0      4
1      4
2      4
3      4
4      4
5      0
6      1
7      1
8      1
9      1
10     1
11     1
12     1
13     1
14     1
15     1
16     1
17     1
18     4
19     1
20     2
21     0
22     0
23   NaN
24   NaN
25   NaN
26   NaN
27     3
28     2
29     4
30     4
31     4
32     4
33     0
34     0
35     0
36     0
37     2
38     2
39     2
40     2
41     1
42     1
43     0
44     2
45     2
46     2
47     2
48     2
49     2
dtype: float64
```